# Can I check if the terminal was started by Visual Studio Code?

Tags: terminal, powershell, visual-studio-code, user-profiles

- I have my VSCode settings configured to start the integrated terminal (using Powershell) in the current workspace folder:

  `"terminal.integrated.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"`

- When I start a Powershell window outside of and unrelated to VSCode I want the default start directory to be my user profile.  I have my Powershell profile configured to start in my home directory (C:\Users\stvhwrd) by default:

  `Set-Location -Path "${env:USERPROFILE}"`

When I open the integrated terminal in VSCode, the profile setting takes precedence over the VSCode setting, so the integrated terminal always starts in my user profile directory.  This is annoying because I then need to `cd` through multiple levels to get to the current project's directory.

How can I configure things such that the integrated terminal will start in the current project directory, while the external [independent] terminal will start in my user profile?

> [<sup>Inspired by this AskUbuntu question</sup>](https://askubuntu.com/a/1134191/787503)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Powershell profile:

`notepad $profile`

Add a conditional check for the [terminal environment keys set by VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/3ce4f1d543cc632c40d300c8204c359f4334cb0a/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/common/terminalEnvironment.ts#L54) on startup:

```
# Set default directory
if ("${env:VSCODE_CWD}" -or "${env:TERM_PROGRAM}" -eq "vscode")
{
    # Allow VSCode settings to determine directory
}
else
{
    Set-Location -Path "${env:USERPROFILE}"
}
```

> [<sup>Inspired by this AskUbuntu question</sup>](https://askubuntu.com/a/1134191/787503)